# primefaces CommandLink underline is not working when mouseover

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
<p:commandLink id="ajax" style="margin-right:20px;">  
            <h:outputText value="Ajax Submit" />  
        </p:commandLink>
```

I want underline when onmouseover.

Comment: check your css file for a:hover. Can bget underline with text-decoration: underline;

Comment: Your question is unclear and incomplete. It's by default *already* underlined. Don't you mean to ask that you want to remove the underline and the let it to appear on mouse over only?

Answer (score -1):

Use CSS Style.

example :

```
<p:commandLink id="mycommandLinkID" .../>
```

CSS Style

```
a.mycommandLinkID:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: This example doesn't work when copypasted into real code. The selector is wrong and even if it was fixed to be a valid ID selector, then it has to be explained clearly that all naming container IDs has to be taken into account, otherwise it will still fail. Don't post halfbaked/untested code. If you can't post valid answer from top of head, experiment it yourself in a real webapp first. Advantage is that you'll *really* learn something this way.